# distinguish scope method of custom directives angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I have this [**`plunker`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0pHqimuqDHBrgFpnDWZM?p=preview) that you could see, you see I use the `scope.click` methods on the link that has a ng-click function on it and I defined the `scope.click = function() {}` inside 'myDirective' custom directive.

The question is when I click the link why it always refer to the second element of the custom directive why can't it refer to both elements? how can I achieve that and also how to distinguish both elements inside the `scope.click` function on 'myDirective' custom directive ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you have no isolated scope defined in your directives. This means hat both directives share the scope with the controller. As you are using your directive two times, you define the `scope.click` event twice, so you overwrite the `scope.click` of the first element. Additionally you overwrite the ng-click of the `<a>` tag.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.click = function() {
     console.log("Inside controller");
  }
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict:'EA',
     scope: {},
     template: "<div ng-click='click()'>click me</div>",
     link:function(scope,elm, attr) {
       scope.click = function() {
         console.log("Inside directive " + attr['id']);
       }
     }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="Test=1;">
    <a href='javascript:;' ng-click="click()">click link</a>

    <my-directive id="elm">
    </my-directive>
  
    <my-directive id="elm2">
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

In this example I define an isolated scope with `scope: {}`. Now each directive has its own scope. Additionally I define the `click()` for each scope.

**UPDATE**

If you really want to execute a function of the directive when clicking on an element outside of the directive you could do it in this way. However, this is not a nice solution. I would generally think about your problem to solve it otherwise.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.click = function($event) {
     $scope.activateElement[$event.target.id]();
  }
  $scope.activateElement = Array();
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict:'EA',
     link:function(scope,elm, attr) {
       scope.activateElement[attr['forid']] = function() {
         console.log("Inside directive " + attr['forid']);
       }
     }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
  <a href='javascript:;' ng-click="click($event)" id='elm'>click link</a>
  <!-- when I click above link, I run the click methods under 'elm' custom directive -->
  <my-directive forid="elm">
  </my-directive>

  <a href='javascript:;' ng-click="click($event)" id='elm2'>click link</a>
  <!-- when I click above link, I run the click methods under 'elm2' custom directive -->
  <my-directive forid="elm2">
  </my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: yes agreed and that's the thing, I don't want to use isolated scope either... the plunker above was just an example, the current custom directive that I build doesn't have any isolated scope in it, could you also probably give some advice based on that ? @boindiil

Comment: So you want a clickable element within the directive which calls a method of your controller?

Comment: humm, not exactly so the ng-click element is set outside the custom directive environment, but when I click the link I want it to match for example the id of the element it self you could see the updated plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/9jRSFyPiTjU1MQCOzHDI?p=preview @boindill

Comment: The id of a html element has to be uniuqe within your document [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp), or does your directive replace the element?. Why not just add your directive as attribute to your link?

Comment: I already update the plunker and the condition inside it could you look at it ? in case you didn't understand my question in the comment section @boindiil

Answer (score 0):

The two directives share the same scope and therefore will overwrite the click function of each other.

If you don't want to use isolated scope and still distinguish each directive you could use one shared click function on the scope and an additional array where the directives will store a callback. The click function will the just call all the registered callbacks:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.clickCallbacks = [];
  $scope.click = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.clickCallbacks, function(callback) {
      callback();
    });
  };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict:'EA',
     link:function(scope,elm, attr) {
       scope.clickCallbacks.push(function() {
         console.log(attr);
       });
     }
   }
});
```

See this working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mCI1BhrExRA1AXo1qkzd?p=preview) as reference.

Comment: wow it works! but the condition that I want probably look like this http://plnkr.co/edit/9jRSFyPiTjU1MQCOzHDI?p=preview could you provide me a solution for this issue ? @DanEEStar